# Is this a valid Stack Overflow question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, close-reasons

I am wondering about this question, which popped up in the close review queue: [8 Queens Algorithm: Not getting full result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899266/8-queens-algorithm-not-getting-full-result-set)

I have read the opinions stated in: [Should we close 'fix my program' questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions)

The above question-of-interest seems to describe the problem, but then it is followed by "why is this happening?" and a block of code.

On one hand I feel like it doesn't show much troubleshooting effort. On the other hand I wonder how much troubleshooting effort could be feasibly shown, and when looking through close reasons, none of the criteria seemed to match exactly. I can't determine if it's a valid question or not. I'm completely on the fence. I did not cast any votes on it.

What do you think?

I see questions of this nature relatively often. I am always fuzzy about them. I'm interested to hear others' opinion on these types of questions.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't need to be closed.

What we mean by 'fix my program' questions are those for which the author doesn't seem to either understand the problem, their solution, or gives no other information than "it doesn't work."

This problem demonstrates that the OP has an understanding of the problem. They've posted something relatively compilable which is their current version of the code. They've posted what happens when they run the code, and the exact question they have (i.e. instead of "It doesn't return the right things," "This returns 4 solutions when it should be returning 92.") To the point of the question you've linked, it is clear what they're asking.

So, I'd say it meets the threshold of a valid question. [Insert plug for re-creating the "too localized" close reason.]

Obviously this question could be a lot better, and I think we both agree on this. But it isn't close-worthy, as it contains all of the information we'd need to help with the problem.

Comment: I'm more inclined to say "we don't really have a close reason that fits" (which is a bit of a problem) as opposed to "it doesn't need to be closed" (many people would probably say "minimal understanding" fits here).