# Are "fix my program" questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138551/candidate-expects-2-arguments-1-provided/20138716), the OP had a bunch of syntax errors in his program. I simply went through and fixed them all, and judging from the fact that he accepted my answer, there was nothing else (in his view) wrong with the program. I also did this for another question, although my answer was slightly incorrect and so I deleted it.

From what I can see, these questions are a bit more rare than your average "fix my typo" questions because it's an entire program, rather than just a missing semi-colon or whatever. However I was wondering if the question is off topic since the only issue was numerous syntax errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A question with a "bunch of syntax errors" that is still focused to a specific programming problem is on-topic (maybe a *Very Low Quality*, though).

A question with a "bunch of syntax errors", which isn't focused, is not only off-topic, but somewhat annoying. In my opinion, the viewers should ask the OP to point at a specific problem rather than going over the code and fixing it all.

Answer (score 1):

It seems my question is already answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions).

As opposed to `Too Localized`, it's suggested they should be closed as [unclear what you're asking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons).

In this situation, it was trivial to fix the errors, and closing the question would have prevented an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20139194/1508519) from being posted. It not only helps the OP, but others who come across the question because the answer is correct and scalable.

I agree with `it's unclear what you're asking` because of the pitfall I fell into when I gave incorrect information, even though the answer I posted allowed the code to compile.

Comment: Too Localized is gone. It was the "propably only helps the op"-question type close reason.

Answer (score -1):

"Debug my code" questions are off-topic on stack overflow.

Close them as <s>Too Localized</s> must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**.

This close reason includes:

- Understanding (readable) compiler/interpreter errors.
- Understanding the basic syntax rules for that language.
- ...

Close it. Now.